# Math needed for Sql Server

Tags: sql, math

I've been working in Sql server jobs since 2 years now. Although I like it, sometimes I get the feeling that at certain times, I stall too much on some tasks, and I seem to be discouraged easily from things that involve relatively simple logic. It's like, at some point I must repeat a logical condition inside my head more than 2 or 3 times in order to understand it completely.

I have the feeling that this might be of my lack of math knowledge. Can anyone please let me know what area of mathematics I can study, that would improve my Sql server coding skills?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field of maths most likely to be useful to you is [Boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic)

Set Theory is good for second place however it will often go into more detail that you are likely to need/use in understanding most sql queries.

A quick cheat that you may find useful is if you feed a boolean expression into wolfram alpha it will spit out a truth table for you which some find a much easier way of visualising the expression.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+or+not+b

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you study symbolic logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reading up on Set based Math.

See this link: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/30/thinking-set-based-or-not.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Set theory helped me somewhat. Studied it in college years before I got into SQL, but being able to think of a bunch of numbers as a semi-amorphous blob of data and not as an ordered list of items really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of this book. It should prove to be most useful: *[The Art of SQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596008949)*, by Stephane Faroult.